# Does SPC show a list of block IDs in the inventory?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, mods

Does SPC already come with a list of blocks when you open your inventory where you can just see and type in the name or number of the block that you wanna replace, Or is that just a different mod?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

SPC doesn't change how your inventory works. For that you want [Too Many Items](http://www.minecraftforum.net/topic/140684-15120-toomanyitems-in-game-invedit-mar-23-release/) (TMI) or [Not Enough Items](http://www.minecraftforum.net/topic/909223-14715-smp-chickenbones-mods/) (NEI). Both if those will let you take items directly out of the list, too, so you won't need to bother with the `/give` command.

To just see the block ID you can just hover the mouse over a block in the list in NEI. (TMI very likely has a similar feature, but I haven't used it personally so I can't give easy directions for how to use it, though I'd be surprised if it's much different.)